# nfs mount authentication failure

Tags: authentication, ubuntu, nfs

I am trying to mount an exported disk on my local machine. I have the following line in my fstab

```
netapp6:/xxx/xxxxx/xxxxxxx /x/xxxxxxx nfs rw,addr=xxx.x.xxx.x 0 0
```

however I get the following error

```
mount.nfs: access denied by server while mounting netapp6:/xxx/xxxxx/xxxxxxx
```

and if I do dmesg I see

```
RPC: server netapp6 requires stronger authentication.
```

I am using Ubuntu 11.10, in a VirtualBox environment. What could be the problem ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Change the Virtualbox settings to use Bridged mode for the network and it should work.

However this does mean that the virtual machine will request its own IP address via DHCP and on some networks, the administrators may restrict DHCP to known MAC addresses, or they might give unknown MAC addresses an address on a VLAN that does not have access to the same networks that you workstation does.